# What do I need to make my receiving coil work?

Tags: led, wireless

[image][image]

I’m working on a wireless energy LEF idea for a buddy's kid who wants to light up his models.

I got the base station with the transmitting coil working and the wireless LEDs I got to work as intended.

The problem I’m having is when I try to create my own wireless LEDs from scratch. I am doing this so we can have the receiving coil closer to the base station, while we have the LED higher up, like in the head of a figure or something similar.

What do I need, or what is the formula I need to use, to figure this part out? I have the circuit that I’m working on posted with this, so please look it over and give me your feedback, it would be greatly appreciated.

Edit one: so the transmitting coil controller does not have a detect function it is either always on or always off. And after looking over the leds that I have, none of hm have a controller either, only a small capacitor.

Comment: What's the box between the buck converter and the transmitting coil?

Comment: Sorry that is the circuit board that controls the transmitting coil

Comment: Why do you need to design the receiving circuit from scratch? Use an existing wireless LED and extend the LED wires to where you want.

Comment: Mostly to learn, and because the wireless leds I have are so small that I feel like I would mess them up.

Comment: It sounds like the receiving coil needs to be connected to a compatible controller which will communicate with the transmitter to establish the power transfer.  I.e. a bare coil will not activate the transmitter.  I'm not sure what standard your base station is using but I believe something like it is fairly common to prevent inductive heating of random metal on the pad.  See page 13 of: https://www.ti.com/general/docs/suppproductinfo.tsp?distId=10&gotoUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fgpn%2Fbq50002a

Comment: Makes sense I was thinking I needed a capacitor or something like that to turn the wave form back into anything I could use, and thank you for the reading material I’m still very new to all this so I’ll take a look and try to parse it all out

Answer (score 1):

There are many DIY projects for wireless power transfer that you can find using those words in a search engine, and you will also find more technical articles and links to experiments performed over 100 years ago as well as modern designs that include high power transfer methods for charging electric vehicles as well as cell phones.

Here are two of many links that show simple DIY projects that include both transmitter and receiver:

https://www.instructables.com/Wireless-Power-Transmission-Over-Short-Distances-U/

https://www.circuits-diy.com/wireless-power-transfer-project-using-555-timer/

If you already have a working transmitter and coil, you should determine the frequency at which it operates, and roughly how much power it consumes. The actual power of transmission will be some fraction of that, and it will diminish according to the distance between transmitter and receiver coil. It will also depend on the geometry and orientation of the transmitter and receiver coils, and the frequency of operation.

The projects shown above generally use coils with about 30 turns of wire, which appear to be enough to light one or more LEDs, which would be in the order of 20 mW. You should use an oscilloscope or a good DMM to determine the operating frequency of the transmitter, and then you should wind a receiving coil with 20-50 turns of insulated wire, perhaps 3 to 6 inches in diameter. Then measure the open circuit AC voltage on the coil at various distances and orientations. If it's more than a few volts, it should work. Now also read the AC current that the coil can produce into a short. The maximum power transfer will be somewhere around half the open circuit voltage and half the short circuit current.

[edit]The receiving coil may need a capacitor to form a resonant LC circuit for maximum efficiency. Your transmitter is specified as 600 kHz, so you may need to measure the inductance of your receiving coil, or just try a few values to see which produces the highest voltage.

If the current is somewhere between 1 and 20 mA, you should be able to wire an LED directly to the receiving coil. Even better, use two in anti-parallel with anodes to cathodes. That way, they will both light, and you won't apply more than the reverse breakdown voltage (about 6V).

This should give you enough ideas to get something working. Report back with details of success or failure. Both are important.

Comment: This is pretty much what I needed I think, I’ve got a working transmitter all wired up and working it’s diameter is 70mm and the wave is 600khz.

Comment: You can use an on-line calculator https://66pacific.com/calculators/coil-inductance-calculator.aspx to determine the inductance of your receiving coil. For instance, 20 turns with 4 inch diameter and 1/2 inch wide is 74 uH. That has a reactance of about 278 ohms at 600 kHz. A capacitor with the same reactance for a resonant circuit is about 950 pF.

Answer (score 1):

PStechPaul has a good answer, but here are some real results. I bought a transmitter/receiver set to play with. It is from the same company, but a slightly different design.

Transmitter: 200mm dia coil, 5 turns of 18 AWG wire. The wire size is more for stiffness than current carrying capability. Freq is 190 kHz. Power draw at 24 VDC is 0.088 A, or a little over 2 W. It uses 2 active components, a small SMT and a large TO-220. Part numbers XKT001, XKT1511. I can find descriptions on the internet, but no datasheet.

Receiver: Overall about 0.22" diameter. 294 turns of 40 AWG wound on a ferrite bobbin. The cap measured 620 pF. Coil, cap, LED in parallel.

I disassembled a receiver. First I removed the cap. The LED still lights, but it is much dimmer. Then I unwound the coil.

Next, I made my own receiver. I had some 34 AWG "magnet" wire. Besides not having any, 40 AWG is really fine, it is fragile, and I can barely see it. 34 AWG is a better choice.

A larger coil should need fewer turns. An air core instead of a ferrite core will require more turns. A guessed that 100 turns on a 0.5" on a wood dowel would work. Wood permability is basically the same as air.

The online formula for inductance assumes that the windings don't overlap, but they are close enough if they do overlap.

If you have a waveform generator, you can measure the inductance. This method only works if the copper resistance of the inductor is small compared to the impedance. Adjust the frequency until VL/Vin = 0.707 (where the impedances are equal). Then L = R/(2Pi * f). I measured 91 uH. Using an online calculator I got 86 uH.

Next, calculate C required for resonance, this occurs where the impedance of the cap equals the impedance of the inductor. 2Pi * f * L = 1 / (2Pi * f * C), or solving for C: C = 1/(L*(2Pi * f )^2) = 7.7 nF for my setup. 8 nF is the closest that I can easily create from my home stock.

Without the caps, the LED is barely detectable. With the caps, the brightness is good, but the range is not quite as good as the original receiver. For better results, add more turns, use a larger coil, or use a ferrite core.

Paul's idea for back-to-back LEDs is a good one, it works.

[For the Mathjax fans out there, sorry, I have used it, but don't have time to refresh my memory right now]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fymfJ3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

[image]

[image]